# How do I make a say command?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, bots

I have this `.say` command, which will make the bot respond with whatever the user entered. For example, `.say hello` should make the bot respond with `hello`.

However, my bot currently responds with `.say hello`. How do I stop the bot from responding with `.say` at the beginning?

I am using the [Pylon](https://pylon.bot) SDK Aka typescript.

```
const commands = new discord.command.CommandGroup({
  defaultPrefix: "."
});

commands.on(
  "say",
  (args) => ({
    input: args.text(),
  }),
  async (message, { input }) => {
    await message.delete();
    await message.reply({
      content: message.content,
      allowedMentions: {},
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple: `message.reply(input);` work for you?

Comment: Its pylon a discord bot

Comment: I've copied the above from the pylon documentation. that should work right?

Answer (score 0):

`message.content` is the original content of the message, including the `.say` at the beginning. What you want to use is `input`, which will be the input of the message (excluding the prefix and command).

Use this instead:

```
await message.reply({
  content: input,
  allowedMentions: {}
})
```

[Here](https://pylon.bot/docs/command-intro#command-with-arguments) is an example of a very similar command in the Pylon documentation.